# Do lexers have to go word by word or can they go line by line

Tags: programming-languages, lexer

So I'm trying to write a interpreter with a lexer. Currently, it adds a token line by line and does some more processing later on. But when I look at sources online, they all seem to go word by word or symbol by symbol. Is there a "correct way" to make a lexer or is tokenizing each line fine?

EDIT:
I realized I didn't explain "line by line" well so here's what I mean. In my interpreter currently, tokens are based on the keyword in the current line(so if it sees a jmp, the entire line is tokenized as JMP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a grammar, then that should be your guide.  Going line-by-line is reasonable in a grammar and would simply include newlines in the grammar as starting or finishing syntactic constructs (rule-defined recognitions).

It is weird to me to say that the line is tokenized as a `JMP`, because that means that the lexer is sensitive to sequence and placement of tokens, which is usually the parser's job — recognition of sequences of input items into syntactic constructs.

To be clear, though, there is no requirement for a lexer at all: a parser can work directly with characters, recognizing things like keyword such as `JMP`, newlines, etc..

One thing that does make a lexer particularly useful tends to be the consumption of white space, comments, conditional compilation sections (#if ... #else .. #endif) as these things, which are in some sense to be ignored by the parser, complicate the parser's recognition job.

---

On the other hand, of course, these things can be made to work with non-traditional divisions of labor between the scanner and parser.  I tend to have my scanners do the above (strip white space, etc..) and yet the parsers still consumes individual characters (so there are no "tokens" assembled by the scanner and fed to the parser).

Comment: Ahhh, ok. I was a little confused on lexers but I think I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*"It depends."*

In early languages such as the original FORTRAN, and some COBOLs, which assumed that input would be provided on 80-column *punched cards,* we have the notion of a **continuation column,** which indicated that the data on "this card" was a continuation of the card which preceded it.  While this concept is fairly archaic now, it may still arise.

Basically, "the purpose of a 'lexer' is to feed the 'parser' the stream of ***tokens*** that it requires," while handling **all** of the 'messy details' so that the rest of the system doesn't have to. ‍♂️

(I vaguely remember one system in which *END_OF_SOURCE_RECORD* was a valid "token type" that the lexer would produce.  *"Whatever works ...")*